# Showing only one toaster

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code below pop a toaster on display:

```
    function showMessage(code, type) {
        ConfigService.getErrorMessage(code).then(
            function (msg) {
                toaster.pop(type, msg);
            }
        );
    }
```

but when I click one time a button I have one toaster, but when I click two, three etc. I have the same number of toaster, but my goal is to have only one toaster, how to do it ? I read a bit about callback but no idea how to apply it.

**EDIT:** Solved

```
        var clicked = false;
        function timeoutInterval(){
            clicked = false;
        }

        // types - error, info, wait, success, warning
        function showMessage(code, type) {
            if(!clicked){
                clicked = true;
                ConfigService.getErrorMessage(code).then(
                    function (msg) {
                        toaster.pop(type, msg);
                        setTimeout(timeoutInterval, 6000);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: the given code isn't enough to tell, little bit i can tell is, toaster should be singleton. Or before opening a toaster make sure you destroy any other instances created already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using a boolean to save the 'state' of the action

```
var clicked = false;
function showMessage(code, type) {

    if (!clicked){ // If the button has not been clicked
        clicked = true;

        ConfigService.getErrorMessage(code).then(
            function (msg) {
                toaster.pop(type, msg);
                clicked = false; // Reset the state of the boolean;
            }
        );
    }
}
```